# Call a webservice(.asmx) from another website/webapp using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, asmx

I am trying to call a webservice(.asmx) file using javascript. Heres a detailed explanation of what I am trying to do.

I have a two WebApplication projects one contains the WebService.asmx file, the other contains the javascript file. I am trying to call the method HelloWorld() located in WebService.asmx from the javascript file.

Note: I am trying to do this without using jQuery.

Please give a detailed explanation (Code and some documentation), I reviewed many examples and tried many different ways none of which worked for me.

Heres a list of things that I have tried:

- Added [ScriptService] to the .asmx file.
- Added Web reference to the project containing the .asmx.
- Added Service reference to the project containing the .asmx.
- Set EnablePageMethods property to true in my script manager.
- Added the following code to my script manager.

  ```
  <Services>
     <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost..." />
  </Services>
  ```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  Is your problem with the service not returning data, or your javascript not calling the service?

Comment: Well last time I've tried it(the closest I've got it to work), I've ran the javascript method like so AppNamespace.Webservice.HelloWorld(callback,fail) and it always jumped to the fail method saying that HelloWorld failed.

Comment: You should use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what error you are getting. The service is running right?  You can run your service directly from visual studio's (make sure the service app is your startup app too). A built in service test page will open so you can test directly against the service.  Make sure its working as you expect first, then start hitting it from your own javascript

Comment: I already know how to work with webservices and I've done a small test using the webservice from code-behind, it worked fine, it got tricky when I started messing with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Since some details are missing from your questions, I would suggest you check the following:

1. The webservice is not hosted on a separate domain that your web application
2. In the HTTP request header, you are passing the proper Content-Type and also the expected Contect-Type
3. Your server returns the same content type as expected by your javascript.
4. If you are using Microsoft's client side AJAX library, ensure you are using the correct serializer/deserializer on the client side.